# Windows 11 Notepad: Command Line Options?

Tags: command-line, windows-11, notepad

Are there command line options in the new UWP app (using a richedit class) similar to [those](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389?msclkid=e669d61ccf6811ec93b20d0a19689ec4) for the Notepad of Windows 10 and previous?
e.g.

> /A  open file as ansi
> /W  open file as unicode
> /P  print filename
> /PT     print filename to designated printer

Comment: Have you tried them in Windows 11?

Comment: No, Windows 11 isn't installed yet.

Comment: Try installing Windows 11 and then ask. I am on Windows 11 here and notepad command lines are reasonably the same as prior versions.

Comment: You have lodged a comment in the Moderator's forum that "Command lines don't work for some" .  I have given you a complete answer and Notepad Command lines work in Windows 11. To troubleshoot issues beyond that, you need to be working in Windows 11.

Comment: @John- Not command lines, rather the _question_ has bruised the sensitivities of our frequent readers. Turns out Notepad command lines have touched some nerves it seems.

Comment: I understand.  There are so many users that we have to have different systems to test.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limited set of Notepad commands (not a common use of Notepad).

[NotePad commands](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389)

Recognized Answer

> There is but a limited set of command line options:
>
> /A  open file as ansi /W  open file as unicode /P
>  print filename /PT   
>  print filename to designated printer There is no switch to
> disable file menu functionality

I have tested /A  /W  and /P on my Windows 11 Pro machine, and they all work. I did not want to try /PT     print filename to designated printer

==============

So to your question:  *Windows 11 Notepad: Command Line Options?*

Same in Windows 11 as in Prior Operating systems.  No apparent change.

To troubleshoot USER issues, you will need to be using Windows 11 yourself.